# How do I setup VSTO for visual studio on mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio, vsto

I have trouble setting up vsto for mac. there is basically no documentation. I do not know if there is even a way to do this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

COM addins in general and VSTO in particular are Windows only. Only the new JS web addins are supported by the macOS version of Office.